# Display element only if there's enough space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I have a table with different messages, one table row always contains one message. The messages also contain the name and the time in their title. The message/table-row width is variable, so if the width is too small there's not enough space for name and time. That's why I'm trying to create a script that sets `.time` to `display: none`, if there's not enough space for it.

This is what I've got so far. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
$( "tr" ).each(function() {
    var width = $(this).width();
    var name = $( ".name" ).width();
    var time = $( ".time" ).width();
    var total = name + time;
        if ( total >= width ) {
            $( ".time" ).css( "display", "none" );
        }
});
```

Comment: When is this code executed? Did debug it? What are the values of the variables?

Comment: Post on http://jsfiddle.net/ with html example

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for all instances of elements which have .name/.time class rather then current element child. Try smth. like this:

```
$( "tr" ).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var width = $this.width();
    var wname = $this.find( ".name" ).width();
    var time = $this.find( ".time" );
        if ( wname + time.width() >= width ) {
            time.css( "display", "none" );
        }
});
```

You can also try setting both time and name to display:inline-block then set tr to overflow-y:hidden if tr height is fixed and equals to name/time height

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to include the container element on each jQuery call:

```
var name = $(".name", this).width();
var time = $(".time", this).width();
```

In your code, you are not selecting the elements expected to run your code.

It would be so good to see a fiddle with your HTML and CSS, to see if it definitely work. Meanwhile, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whj9taxp/), where I make it work with the `ul` element.